# Turn off an always on led with transistor

Tags: led, transistors, switches

I've been trying to turn off a always on led with a push bottom and a transistor? What I want to do is to turn off the led when I push the botton.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftuiFH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Please some help I dont't know why it's not working

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your power supply is 5 volts, not 1 volt. As connected, the NPN transistor will attempt to short-circuit the power supply, which probably won't work. Try

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fs7fHB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much, and yes the Source is 5 volts

Comment: sorry but it's not working :(

Comment: What's not working? The LED is always on? Always off? Transistor on fire? What voltages do you expect at key points in the circuit, and what do you actually get instead?

Comment: The led is always on, but I need to turn it off when I push the button, and it doesn't work as I want, I only whan to turn off the led when I push the button.

Comment: I made somthing wrong, I put R1 between the LED and the Colector, thats why it wasn't working.